# Computer package to compute HOMFLY polynomial?

Tags: computer-algebra

I apologize of already asked by someone else, but what (in your opinion) is the best package for computing HOMFLY polynomials?

Comment: What do you mean by "best"?   Is there something particular you'd like to accomplish? 

Comment: @Ryan: I want to compute the HOMFLY polynomial of (3,19) cable over trefoil.

Comment: The KnotTheory` Mathematica package, available with lots of documentation and examples at http://katlas.org/wiki/Setup, can compute HOMFLY and many other knot polynomials and even produce cables for you automatically.

Comment: @Steven: Thanks, I will try it out!

Comment: There's also http://burtleburtle.net/bob/knot/homfly.html

Comment: @Steven: I have installed the package and it works nice! One more question, how to generate the cable over trefoil in that package?

Comment: @minimax: see http://katlas.org/wiki/Cabling for an example.  You have to import the program CableComponent.m, and then I believe you want to use CableComponent[BR[TorusKnot[19,3]], Knot[3,1]].  (I haven't used CableComponent before, but this knot seems to at least have the right Alexander polynomial according to the formula $\Delta(t) = \Delta_{T_{3,19}}(t) * \Delta_{T_{2,3}}(t^3)$.)